# Can't create a file via shell code in Rails app

Tags: ruby, shellcode

In my ruby script there's a line to create a new file:

```
File.open("/var/test.json", "w")
```

If I call this script from console the file is created. But when I execute shell code in Rails app `%x( ruby script.rb )` the file isn't created. Is there any reason for it? Should I require or include something additional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are not sending the right path to the script, asume you have `script.rb` inside lib:

```
%x( ruby #{Rails.root.join('lib', 'script.rb')} )
```

I think you need to send the full path, but I need more information to know the exact error.

Comment: Yes, it is included